# In swift how does one downcast a UIViewController to subclass of a subclass while retaining data?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Currently I'm working on a project and attempting to downcast from a viewcontroller instantiated from the storyboard using this method

```
let cl = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "contact_list_view")
let contact_list_controller = cl as? ContactListViewController
```

And yes currently the identifier and the view controller type for the view is set in the storyboard. However the problem I'm having is once it downcast the member variables don't persist.

Right now:
ContactListViewController inherits from UITableViewController and that inherits from UIViewController. Is there some sort of issue downcasting in regards to multiple inheritance in an earlier project I was working on I didn't come across this issue using a single level inheritance (A to B instead of currently A to C).

```
@IBAction func switchToContractViewForAdd(_ sender: Any) 
    isAdd_or_edit = true;string = "hello"   
    let contact_view=self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"contact_view")
    self.navigation?.pushViewController(contact_view!, animated: true)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let cl = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "contact_list_view"))
    contact_list_controller = cl as? ContactListViewController
    contact_list_controller?.string ?? "default")
}
```

Alright so here is a snippet of my code basically whats happening is the first function is acting as a segue transition to show the "contact_view". Once the contact view is loaded I want to access some of the values from the previous view "contact_list_view" (for simplicity purposes I added a string variable called string with a default value of "hi" and on the first function call I change it "hello" before performing the segue). After attempting to downcast the the "contact_list_view" when retrieving it from the storyboard the value of string is "hi" once again.

Comment: Any help would be very appreciated. For now I'll continue attempting to look for the answer.

Comment: Probably you get something wrong with the view(Controller)s life cycle. Please be more detailed and show the actual code. How do you set the properties? How do you get them later, to figure out they "don't persist"?

Comment: I apologize if my post seemed vague I added a bit more detail to the post to try and clear up any misunderstandings.

Comment: Do not post images of code. [Edit] your question with actual code (and *please* be sure you format it properly).

Comment: I don't know where you read about "downcasting classes", but if you have it bookmarked you should delete it and never go back. What you want to search for is `swift pass data between view controllers`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason (well, part of the reason) you are not getting the changed value of "hello" is because:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let cl = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "contact_list_view"))
    contact_list_controller = cl as? ContactListViewController
    contact_list_controller?.string ?? "default")
}
```

`instantiateViewController` *creates a new instance of the specified view controller each time you call it.* So, no matter what else you are doing to it after that line, you will never get the value you were trying to set in `switchToContractViewForAdd()`

Instead, you need to look into "passing data between view controllers" (you'll find uncountable examples and explanations out there by simple searching).

Comment: Thank you very much. I was fundamentally looking at the wrong problem. I'm sorry if this might of seemed frustrating for you.